# CoreData Multithreading, Multiple ObjectContexts, DataConcurrency

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios10, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am new to CoreData Multithreaded programming,,,,,

I have two timers which calls two methods for every certain regular intervals of time(means those methods will get executed in backgroundthreads) ,

where one timer method inserts data into coredata DB,other timer method fetches data from same table of coredata DB.

So how do we manage with coredata managedobject Contexts(PrivateQueueConcurrencyTypes)?

Do we need to work with two private managedObjectContexts? 
if so what is the role of performBlock performBlockandwait in it?

thanks

Comment: Check out [Apple's documentation on Core Data concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in different ways depending on your setup. One way is to use the same managed object context and then only save the context inside the performBlockAndWait.